# Windows Authentication: Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\MACHINE$'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, sql-server-2008-r2, asp.net-core-webapi

I have seen many posts with the exact same error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user '**DOMAIN\MACHINE$**'.

but the origin from this exception coud be quite different for each case, here is the explanation of mine:

I am building an API using asp.net core 3.1, the idea is that just some of the active directory users have access to the database behind the scenes.

When running the code from Visual Studio and IIS Express it connects fine, the process is using my active directory user by default to connect.

When publishing the API to my localhost IIS I get this:

- Connecting from browser (**Firefox**) I get the exception, user is 'DOMAIN\MACHINE$', I get not even a prompt requesting the credentials.
- Connecting from **Postman**, at the Auth tab I set Type NTLM Authentication, username, password and domain. Seems is not being used at all as I get same exception as with the Firefox.
- Connecting from a **console application** I created for test purposes, I can get the data perfectly, the console process seems to really use the current user's credentials from windows.

Here the code from the console application:

```
static async Task<string> CallWebApiProtectedAsync(string webApiUrl) 
{
    try
    {
        var uri = new Uri(webApiUrl);
        var credentialsCache = new CredentialCache { { uri, "NTLM", CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials } };
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentialsCache };
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = uri, Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10) };
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var response = httpClient.GetAsync(webApiUrl).Result;
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception in CallWebApiProtectedAsync("+webApiUrl+"):\n" + ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

My goal is to get the API also working for Postman and Firefox, in order to test it in a more flexible way.

Probably I have screwed up any setting from the ASP.NET application itself or from the IIS, not sure at all, I am quite new into this... here some of the settings that may help you to catch the root of all this.

ASP.NET Core API connection string:

> Server=SERVERNAME;Database=DATABASENAME;Trusted_Connection=False;Integrated Security=SSPI;");

I have also tried setting at the Startup class some options like:

```
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();
services.AddAuthentication(HttpSysDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
});        
services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardClientCertificate = true;
});
```

But still same results.

**IIS** configuration for the Authentication is: Windows Authentication enabled. Rest of the entries are disabled (Anonymous, Basic and Digest).

Any idea or suggestion will be highly appreaciated :)

Comment: Did you configured IIS so in the Authentication you have Windows Authentication enabled?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to explain the IIS config. 
Basically just the Windows Authentication setting is enabled. Rest of the authentication entries are disabled.

Comment: If you don't want to grant the machine account access to your database, change IIS application pool identity to a service account, and then let that account access the database.

Comment: @LexLi can you elaborate more on the application pool identity change? what would be a service account in this case?

Comment: Talk to your domain administrators if you don't know what is a service account. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/new-adserviceaccount?view=win10-ps

Comment: @LexLi thanks for the suggestion but in my context the users should have granted rights to the database, so having a generic service account does not work in my context. Otherwise I would not be talking about Windows Authentication :)

Comment: "the users should have granted rights to the database" is usually a terrible idea, as you probably plan to use impersonation. Windows authentication or impersonation should be removed from a modern application, as you can easily find alternative ways (cloudy ready). Think out of the box, and you will find a new world.

Comment: As far as I know, if you don't enable the impersonation in your application, it will use asp.net IIS application pool identity as the user credential to connect to the sql database, That's the reason why you will use 'DOMAIN\MACHINE$'.to access the database, 'DOMAIN\MACHINE$' is your IIS application pool identity account. In my opinion, the most easily way to solve this issue is you modify the database permission setting to allow  'DOMAIN\MACHINE$' account. This means all the user which has successfully login could get the data.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am very much interested in both last of your answers @LexL. You're pointing right to the pain point from the current app architecture. The idea behind is still that some domain wide users have different roles with different permissions... I just haven't seen any API controller example using all this approach...

Comment: Hi @BrandoZhang how do you do the login for an API in this case? Or do you mean having an already logged in into the domain? Still some users from within the domain shoul not be allowed to call any API, should I then check in DB if the user is allowed to get an answer and then return the 401 Unauthorized?

Answer (score 0):

we should update the Identity in application pools in IIS.
[image]

1. select your app and Right click and select Advanced settings
2. update identity with your user name (user name available in the C:\Users) add domain name if anything.

[image]
It was working for me. Thank you.